# python pandas add arguments to function

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to do a pivot_table but in some cases i have to add the margins,
so my code looks like

```
if ytd:
    datak = direct.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Period',
                               values=agg, aggfunc=sum,
                               margins=True,
                               margins_name='Year to date')
else:
    datak = direct.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Period',
                               values=agg, aggfunc=sum)
```

So what i actually want to do is start with something like

exp = (index='Code', columns='Period', values=agg, aggfunc=sum)

marg = (margins=True, margins_name='Year to date')

and finally

datak = direct.pivot_table(exp + marg) if ytd else  direct.pivot_table(exp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
datak = direct.pivot_table(index='Code', columns='Period',
                           values=agg, aggfunc=sum,
                           margins=True if ytd else False,
                           margins_name='Year to date' if ytd else 'All')
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps with `eval`:

```
exp = 'direct.pivot_table(index=\'Code\', columns=\'Period\', values=agg, aggfunc=sum'

marg = 'margins=True, margins_name=\'Year to date\')'

datak = eval(exp + ', ' + marg) if ytd is not None else eval(exp + ')')
```